# Google Analytics API ecommerce data

Tags: javascript, rest, google-analytics, statistics, google-analytics-api

My customers provide me some ecommerce data I want to analyze by Google Analytics and show them as graph on a page or something. I'm kind of mediator between them and Google Analytics.

The point is that they only provide the data to me, they don't communicate with Google Analytics directly, only indirectly via me.

Here's a quote from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037249?hl=en

> https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037249?hl=en
>
> Use ecommerce tracking to find out what users buy through your site or
>   app, including information about:
>
> Products: Which products they buy, in what quantity, and the revenue
>   generated by those products. Transactions: The revenue, tax, shipping,
>   and quantity information for each transaction. Time to Purchase: The
>   number of days and number of sessions it takes to purchase, starting
>   from the most recent campaign through the completed transaction.
>
> .... and so on ...

1. What Google Analytics API methods should I call to provide my customers such the data back?
2. Is it possible at all without having them to inject some javascripts scripts from Google Analytics to their websites?

Comment: First get dirty with the default what google analytics provide and then customized the events for your customer's specific needs. No that is not possible you have to do some integration for customized analytics as per your customer needs

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can ask them to add your gmail account  to their google analytics account with just report read permission so that you to can have the access and for understanding the whole prospect you need to understand the data and den analyse